# Is there a method to get a gradient fill in an svg using css keyframe?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm new to svg, and I wanted to implement a stroke animation onto my portfolio site. I have it working right now but I would like to use a gradient for the fill of the logo once the stroke animation has completed. I tried finding documentation for this but I didn't have much luck finding anything relevant.

I'm looking to have a dark blue at the bottom and a light blue at the top of the text. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

I've got a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/deviouslab/pen/eYOVZyE).

Here's what I've tried so far

```css
@keyframes fill {
    from {
        fill: transparent;
    }
    to {
        fill: linear-gradient(to top, #0070ff, #00c9ff);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to set an SVG linearGradient from which you can make an animation on each color values. example with a simple transition  (hover it) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBWxNdw

Comment: Perfect, that exactly the effect I was aiming for, thank you very much!